# PayPal Integration - Store user account for future payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm looking into implementing PayPal as a payment method for my still in development app and I wanted to make it that the user can save his account the first time he makes a transaction and can select it for future transactions.

Problem is, all the info I find (here, other forums and the docs) is either very old or very confusing. It looks like this is not possible but, as of today, I use a lot of apps that allowed me to save my PayPal account and use it for future payments (Cabify, Uber, Glovo, etc...)

So, does anyone know if this is possible? And if so, point me in the right direction of the documentation?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

With PayPal the ability to save and later reuse the same payment info is called "reference transactions", or sometimes "billing agreements". It is not enabled for PayPal business accounts by default. To request the feature for payment processing, the owner of the PayPal business account should contact PayPal's general business support (note: not technical support) or their account manager and explain the business need for this reference transactions feature.

If it's approved for the account, PayPal can then guide you on which API integration to use, potentially something like the newest v2/vault.

---

The [Braintree Payments gateway](https://www.braintreepayments.com/) includes reference transactions, so that's another way to get the feature.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll ask them also. Do you know if it is possible to store both paypal accounts and credit cards info for future payments? For the people that decide to pay with paypal but without account.

Also, I'm having trouble looking for that vault doc, only get braintree results and atm I'm not planning on using it.

Thanks!

Comment: It is possible; guidance on which APIs to use will have to come from PayPal if approved. Braintree includes all the things.